# NLP: Generate Text from keywords (NLG)

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp

I would like to create an abstract in the end using Natural Language Processing.

As Input I would provide certain keywords belonging to its category.
EG

```
Name -> Sven
Owner -> Felix
Species -> Dog
YearOwned -> 2019
```

Should result into
`„Felix has a dog named Sven. He has him since 2019.“`

But I don‘t know what would be the best way to approach this. I thought about NNs bc I have enough data like this to Train it. But the results I found online were not pretty leading me into hardcoding a Template but this wouldnt be very flexible if one data value is missing or has two entries.

Maybe someone has an idea how I could best approach this.

Tyvm Taka

Ideally the resulting text should consist out of multiple sentences. Bc more data would follow.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how intensive this project is, but I suggest looking into Graph Databases, like [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com) or [DGraph](http://graph.io) (depending on if you want a semantic ontology or a labeled property graph).

The premise of how these services work is that you store your data as **triples** where you have nodes being the subject and object, and edges being the predicate. So in your example , we would have an object node for Human and Dog, with an edge between them being Years Owned:

```
Human ---- owns ----- > Dog
```

We could the store an RDF Triple (think of it like an instance of the objects listed above) as:

```
Sven ---- owns ----> Felix
```

And we can have properties on the edge, so a property on 'owns' would be 'since year', in which case  you would have 2019.

```
Sven ---- owns ----> Felix
           |
          since: 2019
```

This might not be the simple NLP fix you are looking for, but I highly suggest looking into graph databases as they are a great way of implementing relation extraction in a way that simple NLP algorithms cannot.